# readdir(): 33 is not a valid Directory resource

Tags: php

I know we have duplicates of this but still not getting exact solution. Here is my code

```
if ($lib_dir = @opendir($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/lib")) {
    while (false !== ($lib_file = readdir($lib_dir))) {
        if ((preg_match("/\.php$/", $lib_file)) & ($lib_file!="loader.php"))     
        {
            include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/lib/$lib_file");
        }
    }
    closedir($lib_dir);
```

}

Thanx in advance

Comment: in if you are doing assignment `=` you need `==`.

Comment: @Suchit [That is valid PHP code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681075/while-loop-in-php-with-assignment-operator).

Comment: Tried == still not working