# How does while loop work with mysqli_fetch_assoc()?

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

This is probably a silly beginner question and i don't think it's limited to mysqli_fetch_assoc() so it's probably a general programming question.

Anyways, i have this PHP code for getting data from a database using mysqli

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM table1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if($result){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

What i don't understand is how the while loop there works. How does it iterates to the next element and know when to end? mysqli_fetch_assoc() returns a associative array which is stored in row variable which means it is not null therefore true and let's the while loop run. What i don't understand is how it iterates through the rows and ends when there are no more rows left. I'm not specifically doing anything to change the row to the next one so how does it do it on it's own?

Also mysqli_fetch_assoc() returns a associative array so shouldn't "name" key contain 1 element? Or is it a array of all the rows in that column?

(I hope you can understand what i'm trying to say, i'm not the best at explaining .-.)

Edit: What i don't understand is how this code iterates through all the rows. Is it part of the "inbuilt code" in this function? (I couldn't find it anywhere to confirm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [while loop in php with assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681075/while-loop-in-php-with-assignment-operator)

Comment: You should also read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317259/why-are-assignments-in-conditions-bad

Comment: `$row` is an associative array, which means it will contain exactly one key => value pair.  In your case, it contains `['name'] => 'Some value'` - so yes, it contains 1 element *in this case*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time when 
`mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` is accessed, the **pointer** moves to the **next record**. At last when **no records** are found, it returns **`null`** which breaks the `while` condition.

Comment: Is the moving of pointer to the next record part of the function's code?

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where i can read the code for the function?

Comment: These are core functions. It is the part of mysqli php extension. These are compiled libraries written in c, c++ etc.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, when `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` runs out of rows it will return NULL, which evaluates to false, which breaks out of the loop.

`$row` results in a single row in the database, so `$row['name']` would be the value of 'name' for a particular row.

Let's break it down, with perhaps a dumbed down example of how it works internally (Please note, this works a lot more efficiently, and wont actually run multiple queries):

```
$result = ['currentRow' => 0, 'query' => 'SELECT name FROM table1'];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_result($result)) {
}

//First iteration
mysqli_fetch_result queries 'SELECT name FROM table1 LIMIT 0, 1'
it increments internally $result['currentRow'] to 1
it returns the row that was found

//Second iteration
mysqli_fetch_result queries 'SELECT name FROM table1 LIMIT 1, 1'
it increments internally $result['currentRow'] to 2
it returns the row that was found

//Third iteration
mysqli_fetch_result queries 'SELECT name FROM table1 LIMIT 2, 1'
no rows returned! Just simply return null (This will cause your while loop to break out)
```

Comment: When does it run out of rows? I mean i'm not iterating through the rows so shouldn't it always be the first row or something?

Or is the iteration part inbuilt in the function?

Comment: @Uzer When you run out of rows in the database. If there's only 10 rows in table1, then when mysql gets to the end of the table, there's no more rows to grab. It will return NULL at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You always pass [`$result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) as an argument to [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). This argument holds the iterator information, which will be used by `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to advance each time you call this function to the next row.

During each iteration, `$row['name']` will be a single string.