# WHILE LOOP + mysqli_fetch_object

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I don't understand *why* this code works:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    echo $row->id . " ";
    echo $row->first_name . " ";
    echo $row->last_name . "<br>";
}
```

This is a part of a tutorial on CRUD that I am learning. The while loop goes through the whole table and lists all the rows and columns. But from my understanding of `while`-loops, this shouldn't work.

My guess would be that it should try to print out the current row infinite times and crash my browser as there is no change in the condition. Why does it go through all the rows? Why does it stop? I can't find answer to this anywhere.

Would there be anyone kind enough to explain in simple terms?

Comment: Each fetch gets a row and succeeds which evaluates to true so the while loop continues. When there are no more rows available to fetch the fetch returns false and the while loop ends.

Comment: @Dave This should be posted as an answer not a comment

Comment: Can you explain **why** you don't understand that code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [while loop in php with assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681075/while-loop-in-php-with-assignment-operator)

Answer (score 3):

Each fetch gets a row and succeeds which evaluates to true so the while loop continues. When there are no more rows available to fetch the fetch returns false and the while loop ends.

Comment: Note that PHP internally uses pointers. Every time a result is fetched, the pointer moves forward in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

You assume that the condition does not change. That's where you are wrong. You can reassign values *inside* the while condition.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
```

`mysqli_fetch_object`'s result gets stored in the `$row` variable on each iteration. The `$row` variable will be evaluated as a boolean, and if `$row` is an object, it will be truthy and hence go inside the loop body.

So on the first iteration, you'll get the first `$row`, then the second, and so on.

If there are no more rows `mysqli_fetch_object` will return `null`. `Null` will be stored in the `$row` variable and evaluated. `Null` is a falsely value and hence the loop will break.

You are most likely misreading the condition in your brain as either:

- `$row == mysqli_fetch_object($result)`
- `$row === mysqli_fetch_object($result)`

This changes the meaning completely.

---

Sidenote: Reassignment in conditions is something that php allows at different places as well and may lead to hard-to-debug bugs.

E.g. `if ($bool = false) { echo "I never will be printed";}` is valid php and will always lead to a `false` check and hence never execute the true-branch.